# A shared pointer which can delete the managed object before the usage count reaches zero

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template, pointers

When I was working on my game engine, I needed to know if a game object has been destroyed or not. So, I decided to use `std::shared_ptr`. But the standard shared pointer is not able to delete the managed pointer before the usage count reaches zero. So I decided to write my own implementation.

This is the header file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

#define usage_count_type uint16_t

class RefCounter {
public:
    usage_count_type count = 0;
    bool destroyed = false;

    RefCounter() {}

    RefCounter(const RefCounter&) = delete;
    RefCounter& operator=(const RefCounter&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
class SharedPtr {
    T* pointer;
    RefCounter* counter;

public:
    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
        pointer = ptr;
        counter = new RefCounter();
        counter->count++;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<T>& sp) {
        pointer = sp.pointer;
        counter = sp.counter;
        counter->count++;
    }

    // Overload = operator for another shared pointer
    SharedPtr<T>& operator=(SharedPtr<T>& sp) {
        counter->count--;
        if (counter->count == 0) {
            if (!counter->destroyed) delete pointer;

            delete counter;
        }

        pointer = sp.pointer;
        counter = sp.counter;
        counter->count++;

        return *this;
    }

    // Overload = operator for pointer of type T
    SharedPtr<T>& operator=(T* object) {
        counter->count--;
        if (counter->count == 0) {
            if (!counter->destroyed) delete pointer;
        }

        pointer = object;
        counter->count = 1;

        return *this;
    }

    uint16_t use_count() {
        return counter->count;
    }

    bool is_destroyed() {
        return counter->destroyed;
    }

    void destroy() {
        delete pointer;
        counter->destroyed = true;
    }

    // Get the pointer
    T* get() {
        return pointer;
    }

    // Overload * operator
    T& operator*() {
        return *pointer;
    }

    // Overload -> operator
    T* operator->() {
        return pointer;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~SharedPtr() {
        counter->count--;
        if (counter->count == 0) {
            if (!counter->destroyed) delete pointer;

            delete counter;
        }
    }
};
```

And this is a simple usage example:

```cpp
#include "pointers.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Entity {
    std::string name = "entity";

    ~Entity() {
        std::cout << "destructing entity: " << name << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    SharedPtr<Entity> e1(new Entity());
    e1->name = "Entity-1";
    std::cout << "usage count of Entity-1: " << e1.use_count() << '\n';

    SharedPtr<Entity> e2;
    SharedPtr<Entity> e3;

    e2 = e1;
    e3 = e2;
    std::cout << "usage count of Entity-1: " << e1.use_count() << '\n';

    SharedPtr<Entity> e4;
    e4 = new Entity();
    e3 = e4;
    e3->name = "Entity-2";
    std::cout << "Name of the new entity: " << e4->name << '\n';

    std::cout << "usage count of Entity-1: " << e1.use_count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "usage count of Entity-2: " << e4.use_count() << '\n';

    std::cout << "killing Entity-1\n";
    e2.destroy(); //You can destroy the managed object from any of the shared pointers
    std::cout << "Is Entity-1 alive: " << !e1.is_destroyed() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Shared pointer is not for the beginner (unless you are using as a learning excercise). Also you have a bug in `SharedPtr<T>& operator=(T* object)` that breaks it. Will be back with a review later. What about `std::weak_ptr`?

Comment: Hi @MartinYork . I implemented this shared pointer to be able to detect if an entity is alive from several parts of the game engine and to know if there's still any entity which uses a specific asset or not.

Comment: Updated my review. Found four major bugs and have some other pointers you should attend to.

Comment: what is the point of deleting an object with none-zero use count? why not use `std::weak_ptr` if you don't intend to extend the lifetime of a shared pointer?

Comment: @MartinYork thanks for your in depth review

Comment: @Red.Wave it isn't only about extending lifetime of an object. I implemented reference count to be sure there wouldn't be any memory leak.

Comment: @MohammadArminNiknami then `delete`ing a pointer with none_zero `use_count` defeats the purpose. The fact that reference count is not zero shows that some other object is dependent on this pointer and will cause **use-after-free**, if this pointer is destroyed.

Comment: @Red.Wave I made it with the idea that it would be checked for eligibility every time before use.

Comment: @MohammadArminNiknami that is just wrong usage. If you just want to check the validity of the pointer, it must not own the object. That's why `std::shared_ptr` has a companion `std::weak_ptr`; the former always assumes validity of object and owns it, while the later never owns the object and always checks for validity. `weak_ptr::lock` method returns either a `nullptr` or a valid `shared_ptr`; validity can be checked after calling `lock` by simply  checking against `nullptr` or conversion to `bool`. End of discussion.

Answer (score 6):

### Overview

Personally I would always put my code in its own unique namespace. I don't think `SharedPtr` is going to be that unique and you don't want to have an accidental clash.

Shared pointers are not easy to get correct.
There is a famous article by Scott Myers about his attempt at shared pointers for one of his books. Where he was getting corrections for several years after the attempt.

Now don't get me wrong. I think everybody should try. Its a good exercise. **BUT** nobody should use anything but a "standard" (well tested) shared pointer because of the easy holes that you will fall into.

I found four situations where your smart pointer is broken.

- Constructor
- Standard Copy assignment
- Pointer assignment
- The destroy can be used multiple times (double delete issue)

It makes me squirm a bit that a nullptr will have a reference count and when a smart pointer holding a `nullptr` is copied that reference counter is incremented.

Additionally the code in two constructor and destructor is repeated (testing for zero reference count and deleting the object and counter). This you should simplify (KISS and Clean Code) by factorizing common repeated code into a function that is used from all these places.

I would also like to be able to use move semantics with a smart pointer, so I personally think you should add move semantics to your object (but if you have a simpler use case then maybe you can justify not having it (and you should justify it in some comments)).

You don't write `const` correct code so you need to pay a bit more attention there.

There is a some missing/broken functionality (seem my articles for more details). But things like `nullptr` construction and testing for equality are missing.

See my articles on smart pointers for more reading:

[UniquePointer](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Smart-Pointer-UniquePointer)
[SharedPointer](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Smart-Pointer-SharedPointer)
[Smart-Pointer Constructors](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Smart-Pointer-Constructors)

### Code Review

I don't like this.

```
#pragma once
```

It's not portable. And it's so simple to do it the standard way!

---

The use of `#define` is exceedingly rare in C++. In C it is needed for a lot of situations but most of those situations have specific C++ idioms that are type safe and idiomatic.

```
#define usage_count_type uint16_t
```

The C++ way of doing this:

```
using usage_count_type = uint16_t;
```

---

OK: You have a ref counter.

```
class RefCounter {
public:
    usage_count_type count = 0;
    bool destroyed = false;

    RefCounter() {}

    RefCounter(const RefCounter&) = delete;
    RefCounter& operator=(const RefCounter&) = delete;
};
```

Potentially allowing the user to delete the object before `0` is reached and tracking that. The standard allows this via `std::weak_ptr` with slightly better semantics than you propose.

Missing optimizations where the value and counter can be allocated at the same time for efficiency (if you want).

But OK as a starting point.

---

First issue is that you are not using the initializer list.

```
    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
        pointer = ptr;
        counter = new RefCounter();
        counter->count++;
    }
```

OK. It does not matter in this version since they are pointers so you are not losing anything **NOW**. But one of the major way things get updated in C++ is to simply change the type of a member. This may result in your code becoming not optimal if you are not using the initializer list. So get into the habit of using the initializer list to make sure you always generate optimal code.

```
    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept
        : pointer{ptr}
        , counter{new RefCounter()}
    {
        counter->count++;
    }
```

---

OK. Your first real issue.

```
    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
        pointer = ptr;
        counter = new RefCounter();
        counter->count++;
    }
```

The use of `noexcept` is wrong here. You are trying to tell the compiler this function can't have an exception. But it can: `new` has the potential of throwing. If it does throw, then an exception here ends the program without unwinding the stack and therefore without calling any destructors. This is a bad idea.

So we should correct to remove the `noexcept`.

What happens if the `new` fails? You have now leaked the `ptr` that passed in as a parameter.

The point of this constructor is you pass a pointer (intending for the object to take ownership and manage the pointer) and no matter what happens you must make sure that this pointer is not leaked. That means if an an exception happens during the constructor you must release the pointer (because if an exception escapes the constructor then the destructor will never be called).

```
    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr)
    try
        : pointer{ptr}
        , counter{new RefCounter()}
    {
        counter->count++;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        delete ptr;
        throw;
    }
```

---

OK you have a copy constructor.

```
    // Copy constructor
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<T>& sp) {
        pointer = sp.pointer;
        counter = sp.counter;
        counter->count++;
    }
```

Looks very standard. But again I would use the initializer list.

```
    // Copy constructor
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<T>& sp)
        : pointer{sp.pointer}
        , counter{sp.pointer}
    {
        counter->count++;
    }
```

---

OK second mistake is in the copy assignment operator:

2: No check for self assignment.

```
   int main()
   {
       Shared_ptr<int>  a(new int(12));
       a = a;
          // Decrements the counter.
          // Destroys the object.
          // Destroys the "counter"
          // Makes it point at its orignal value.
          // increments the **DELETED** counter object!!!

          // a is now completely invalid.
   }
```

Let's walk through the assignment operator:

```
    SharedPtr<T>& operator=(SharedPtr<T>& sp) {
        // Note: this and &sp are the same.

        // This is the only reference to the counter.
        counter->count--;
        // So decrementing it will cause it to reach zero.
        if (counter->count == 0) {
            // It has not been destroyed before
            // So destroy the object.
            if (!counter->destroyed) delete pointer;

            // destroy the counter.
            delete counter;
        }

        // This just assings the same values back.
        // Both point at deleted objects.
        // **BUT** destroyed is still "false" in the released
        // memory so even if nothing bad happens soon
        // you are going to eventually get a double call to delete
        // on this memory in the futre.
        pointer = sp.pointer;
        counter = sp.counter;

        counter->count++;

        return *this;
    }
```

A lot of beginners will simply check for assignment to self and return immediately if this happens. But this is a rare situation and by using this technique you are pessimizing the normal operation (the normal situation is not self assignment). So the better technique is to use the copy and swap idiom.

```
     // Notice the parameter is passed by value.
     // This effectively makes a copy of the object
     // what is required in normal situations.
     SharedPtr<T>& operator=(SharedPtr<T> sp)
     {
         std::swap(pointer, sp.pointer);  // You are copying the content
         std::swap(counter, sp.counter);  // out of the newly created object.
         return *this;
     }
     // At this point the parameter `sp` is destroyed.
     // This will call release on any pointer via the destructor
     // if this was the only reference to the object.
```

---

Your assignment with a RAW pointer is also broken:

```
// Overload = operator for pointer of type T
SharedPtr<T>& operator=(T* object) {

    // This part is correct.
    counter->count--;
    if (counter->count == 0) {
        if (!counter->destroyed) delete pointer;
    }

    pointer = object;

    // But you can't re-use this counter if the count is not zero.
    // This counter object may already be being used by other
    // objects.
    counter->count = 1;

    return *this;
}
```

3: You increment the counter that could potentially point at another object.

Think about this:

```
 int main()
 {
     SharedPtr<int>  a(new int(14));
     SharedPtr<int>  b(a);
     SharedPtr<int>  c(a);

     c = new int(15);
     // Note: This decrements the counter.
     //       But then re-uses the counter object.
     //       Which is the same object that is being used
     //       by both a and b but now the count is 1
     //       even though all three variables are using the same counter
     //       and two of them have different pointers associated!
}
// When these variables go out of scope
// only c will be deleted.
// variables b and a will have a negative count (or very large)
// and thus the associated memory is leaked.
```

Again the solution is to use Copy and Swap idiom:

```
SharedPtr<T>& operator=(T* object) {
     // This effectively makes a new smart pointer
     SharedPtr<T> sp(object);

     std::swap(pointer, sp.pointer);  // You are copying the content
     std::swap(counter, sp.counter);  // out of the newly created object.
     return *this;
}
// At this point the local variable `sp` is destroyed.
// This will release via the destructor any value that was being pointed at.
```

---

You don't check if the pointer has already been destroyed!

```
void destroy() {
    delete pointer;
    counter->destroyed = true;
}
```

This could result in a double delete if multiple different pointers try and release the memory.

```
void destroy() {
    // Make sure you check it is not already deleted.
    if (!counter->destroyed) {
        delete pointer;
        counter->destroyed = true;
    }
}
```

---

Mark these functions as `const`:

```
    uint16_t use_count() {
        return counter->count;
    }



    bool is_destroyed() {
        return counter->destroyed;
    }
```

It does not change the state so let the compiler know it is safe to use in const context.

---

Sure this works:

```
    // Get the pointer
    T* get() {
        return pointer;
    }

    // Overload * operator
    T& operator*() {
        return *pointer;
    }

    // Overload -> operator
    T* operator->() {
        return pointer;
    }
```

But what if your shared pointer is `const`? You may still want to use what is in the object (reading any values). So you should also have const versions of these functions:

### Retry:

I am now going to make the same mistake as Scott Myers and show what I would do.

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SMARTPTR_H
#define THORSANVIL_SMARTPTR_H

#include <cstdint>

namespace ThorsAnvil::SmartPtr
{

using UsageCount = uint16_t;


template <typename T>
class SharedPtr {
    class RefCounter {
    public:
        UsageCount count = 0;
        bool destroyed = false;
    
        RefCounter() {}
    
        RefCounter(const RefCounter&) = delete;
        RefCounter& operator=(const RefCounter&) = delete;
    };

    T*          pointer;
    RefCounter* counter;

public:
    SharedPtr(std::nullptr_t)
        : pointer( nullptr )
        , counter( nullptr )
    {}

    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = nullptr)
    try
    {
            : pointer{ ptr }
            , counter{ ptr ? new RefCounter() : nullptr}
        {
            increment();
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        delete ptr;
        throw;
    }

    ~SharedPtr()
    {
        decrement();
    }

    // Copy constructor
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr& sp) noexcept
        : pointer{ sp.pointer }
        , counter{ sp.counter }
    {
        increment();
    }

    // Move constructor
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr& sp) noexcept
        : pointer{ std::exchange(sp.pointer, nullptr) }
        , counter{ std::exchange(sp.counter, nullptr) }
    {}

    // Overload = operator
    // Both Copy and Move in a single function.
    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr sp) noexcept
    {
        swap(sp);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(SharedPtr& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(pointer, other.pointer);
        swap(counter, other.counter);
    }

    friend void swap(SharedPtr& lhs, SharedPtr& rhs)
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }

    // Overload = operator for pointer of type T
    SharedPtr& operator=(T* object)
    {
        SharedPtr sp(object);
        swap(sp);
        return *this;
    }

    uint16_t use_count() const {
        return counter ? counter->count : 0;
    }

    bool is_destroyed() const {
        return counter ? counter->destroyed : true;
    }

    void destroy() {
        if (!is_destroyed()) {
            delete pointer;
            counter->destroyed = true;
        }
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return !is_destroyed();
    }

    // Get the pointer
    T*       get()              {return pointer;}
    T const* get() const        {return pointer;}

    // Overload * operator
    T&       operator*()        {return *pointer;}
    T const& operator*() const  {return *pointer;}

    // Overload -> operator
    T*       operator->()       {return pointer;}
    T const* operator->() const {return pointer;}

private:
        void increment()
        {
            if (counter) {
                ++counter->count;
            }
        }
        void decrement()
        {
            if (counter) {
                --counter->count;
                if (counter->count == 0)
                    if (!counter->destroyed) {
                        delete ptr;
                    }
                    delete counter;
                }
            }
        }

};

}
#endif
```

Comment: Hi Martin York. I had got COVID-19 and couldn't answer the reviews.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth review. I'm going to fix all the problems which you have listed and will upload the new code soon.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `std::weak_ptr`

> So, I decided to use `std::shared_ptr`. But the standard shared pointer is not able to delete the managed pointer before the usage count reaches zero.

Indeed, that is the case if you just use `std::shared_ptr`. However, you can use [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to get a handle to a `std::shared_ptr` that doesn't affect the reference count.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Entity {
    ~Entity() {
        std::cout << "Destructing entity\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto e1 = std::make_shared<Entity>();
    auto e2 = std::weak_ptr(e1);
    std::cout << "Use count before: " << e2.use_count() << '\n';
    e1.reset();
    std::cout << "Use count after: " << e2.use_count() << '\n';

    if (auto e3 = e2.lock()) {
        std::cout << "Object still alive\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Object deleted\n";
    }
}
```

And all this is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Just curious what is the use case? If game engine is already using an `std::shared_ptr` then it will be destroyed only when the `count` is `0`. If it does not do that then sticking a pointer to game objects in an `std::shared_ptr` is dangerous. Once the pointer goes out of scope it will call `delete` on the memory location and if the game engine used anything other than `new` to allocate the object, you just invoked undefined behavior. And even if the Game engine uses `new`, you just created a potential use after free. If you are creating an object via `shared_ptr` and giving it to the game engine to manage then you can have similar undefined behaviors too.

I will assume you have no use case for a custom deleter so it is not implemented.

1. Dont use `#pragma once` different platforms implement it differently. Use `#define` header guards instead.
2. Use `using usage_count_type = uint16_t` not a macro.
3. You dont have delete copy assignment and construction for `RefCounter`. It does not need a constructor either.
4. `SharedPtr` constructor is not `noexcept` it makes an allocation in it body which means it can throw
5. Use copy-swap idiom to implement copy and move constructors and assignment operators.
6. Copy constructors take a `const` reference not a non-`const` reference
7. Implement move assignment. Look up rule of 5.
8. Implement `const-qualified` versions of dereference operators and `get()`
9. Implement `operator bool` and `comparision` operators
10. `use_count()` must `const` and `noexcept`
11. Combine nested `if` like this `if(counter->count == 0 && !counter->destroyed)`
12. `Counter` must be thread safe.

Comment: Re 6: Even if the source must be a mutable lvalue it is still a copy-constructor/-assignment. It's just much less useful to the consumer for most of the time no gain to the implementer, and thus very uncommon. Re 7: Some rationale would be nice. Re 8: Why const versions instead of making the current ones const-qualified?

Comment: @Deduplicator Re6: Yes, it is a copy assignment/ctor. It is not as useful for the consumer. This copy ctor will fail to compile if the source is const. It will also fail to compile if we try to assign a temporary eg function returns. There is a serious gain to the implementer. It prevents them from mistakely changing the copied from object. Here is an example https://godbolt.org/z/TM5b8G91c. Re 7: Look up rule of five. Re 8: I meant const qualified. Made edits to 7, 8.